# Cloud Dataflow metric on dropped late messages

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Does Apache Beam emit any metric on how many (late) messages are dropped?

Whether it is on `DirectRunner` or `DataflowRunner`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a `droppedDueToClosedWindow` metric while running the pipeline on Cloud Dataflow.